# Elasticsearch exception unrecognized parameter ccs_minimize_roundtrips

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am getting the following error while searching data from elasticsearch through spring data jpa

```
23-11-2021 19:51:20.699 [http-nio-8990-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=request [/dummy/_doc/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [ccs_minimize_roundtrips]]]] with root cause
```

Here is my maven dependancies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I think the ES server version and api version is same but i am still getting this error.

N.B This is not the duplicate because i am getting this error even in older version

Comment: The 3.2.3 spring-data-elasticsearch version [requires](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions) Elastic 6.8.12. Can you concretely tell us which ES version you're running?

Comment: and please show the code you use for the query

Comment: @Val After manually adding elasticsearch 6.7.1 i got several error but then added elasticsearch-rest-client 6.8.4 and elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 6.8.4, now works properly. You may add this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ccs_minimize_roundtrips` parameter has been added in [7.0.0-beta1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/37828), so my take is that you're using a client version that is more recent (i.e. 7+) than your Elasticsearch server version.

According to your Maven dependencies, `spring-data-elasticsearch:3.2.3` [depends on Elastic 6.8.12](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#preface.versions), so there is a small disconnect between the client and server versions.

Comment: N.B this answer solves my problem but i also had to add elasticsearch 6.7.1, elasticsearch-rest-client 6.8.4 and elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 6.8.4